# What would English sound like if the Normans were Spanish?

Tags: movement

In 1066, a group of French soldiers entered Britain. They spread French with them, and French became the language of nobility. In fact, 30% of our words are French. How would our English be different if the Normans were Spanish and the Great Vowel Shift happened the same way? Guess: v would be pronounced b.

I’m asking this because Spanish is my second language and it is also the second most spoken language in the US, with a majority of native born bilinguals, including me learn it.

Comment: I'm voting to close because it's too speculative. But you should consider asking it at the [conlang.se] site instead.

Comment: Vice versa, *b* became *v* in many cases (e.g. in *love*). So it looks like the Spanish were there indeed and hypercorrected :D silly question though. Language change is among other things a matter of socio-linguistics and thus depends on the culture. For sake of the argument, nothing would have changed, because Slanish is too different, whereas Norman had Germanic influences to begin with.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=A-RfHC91Ewc

Comment: ... I mistakenly clicked the "Leave open" button. It may not be any use now, but I actually agree with @curiousdannii on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that those Scandinavians from Normandy in France were speakers of Spanish and not French, also that the invasion was still in 1066, English would sound more or less the same except that some borrowed lexical items would be different. For instance, *palaver* might be a regular word, not pirate talk, and "pay" would probably have a *g*. There would be a distinction between *v* and *b* just as there was in Old Spanish (Old Spanish didn't sound like Modern Spanish). The vast majority of English speakers did not speak French and did not pick up French phonetic patterns, so likewise then would not speak Spanish and would not pick up Spanish phonetic patterns. When, over the centuries, Spanish words became part of English, the phonetics of the ruling class would probably assimilate to English and etymologically Spanish words would not have any phonemes or sequences that distinguished them from non-Spanish English words.